# Multiply a specific column in each row by -1

Tags: pytorch

I have a pytorch tensor A, that's of size (n,m) and a list of indices for size n, such that each entry of 0 <= indices[i] < m. For each row i of A, I want to multiply A[i, indices[i]] *= -1, in a vectorized way. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
 A = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
 indices = torch.tensor([1, 2])

 #desired result
 A = [[1,-2,3],[4,5,-6]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is, [fancy indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) is the way to go:

```
import torch

A = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
indices = torch.tensor([1, 2]).long()

A[range(A.shape[0]), indices] *= -1
```

**Remember indices must be `torch.LongTensor` type**. You could cast it if you have `float` using `.long()` member function.